# Capybara fails on Accept_Confirm

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am trying to set up a test for a validation in a "Link_to" helper in rails when it has a => data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}

I have tried Accept_confirm and Accept_Alert but none of this has worked. The errors shows: Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#accept_modal

```rb
describe 'delete' do
     it 'y existe un enlace para borrar Post' do
      @post = FactoryBot.create(:post)
      visit posts_path
      accept_confirm("Are you sure?") do
        click_link("delete#{@post.id}")
      end
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

```
<td>
  <%= link_to 'Borrar', post_path(post), method: :delete, id: "delete#{post.id}", data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>
</td>
```

The complete error message says:
 1) navegate delete y existe un enlace para borrar Post
     Failure/Error:
       accept_confirm("Are you sure?") do
         click_link("delete#{@post.id}")
       end

```
 Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
   Capybara::Driver::Base#accept_modal
 # ./spec/features/post_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your tests using a driver which doesn't support JS (probably the default `rack_test` driver). As such JS driven modal boxes can't show up, and the modal handling methods aren't supported. You'll have to run your tests via a driver that supports JS if you want to use JS features of the page - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `js: true` to switch to the Capybara.javascript_driver

```rb
describe 'delete', js: true do
  it 'y existe un enlace para borrar Post' do
    @post = FactoryBot.create(:post)
    visit posts_path
    accept_confirm("Are you sure?") do
      click_link("delete#{@post.id}")
    end
    expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

Documentation here : https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#using-capybara-with-rspec